# Device Power State Failure, Windows 10

Tags: laptop, windows-10, graphics-card, bsod, display-driver

Basically, I got a new laptop from ASUS, the [N551JW](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/N551JW/). It's a great device all around, but sometimes, I get a BSOD (Device Power State Failure). I have hunch it's the graphics card driver, because it happens (at least the last 5 bloody times) when my computer is on battery mode and I leave Unity running in the background. When I switch back to Unity it is frozen and then it's just a matter of time before the BSOD hits. But still, maybe it's the Intel integrated card or something completely random.

If anybody could take the time of day to help me out with this, I would appreciate it a lot, because it's driving me nuts.

Here are the dumps: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dmgdvxmqyzmps7m/AAC7RUXGYULEfJHKk5EGRGBpa?dl=0

Comment: have you tried the newer driver?

Comment: Yes, and the one from the ASUS website, same thing is still happening when unplugged..

Comment: if you still see this issue, report it in the nVIDIA forums: https://forums.geforce.com/default/board/33/geforce-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

Your [DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559329(v=vs.85).aspx) `- A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time` crash sames to be caused by your nVIDIA driver:

```
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
04 dxgkrnl!DpiFdoHandleDevicePower
05 dxgkrnl!DpiDispatchPower
06 nvlddmkm
07 0x0
08 0x0
09 0x0

Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Sat Oct 03 04:08:52 2015
```

Your driver is from October, so try to [install a newer one directly from nVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/96885/en-us).